# How auto-scrolling lyrics feature is implemented in Android? (UI point of view)

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, autoscroll

Its been a while I'm developing android applications but I haven't come across such a **"View"** in Android that facilitates the auto-scrolling. What is the Android **"View Component"** that might have been possibly used in e.g. Spotify's auto-scrolling mechanism
First I thought it would be a video synced with song's time but since, we can move it up and down, that might not be the case. How auto-scrolling is implemented in such way?

Answer (score 0):

You can send some data from your sever to client app which contanis the pace of the singer inside that song because this time is different per every song as you know.
However, for implementing these kind of functionalities, you can call a function over and over which is responsible to scroll the content on every call. And to prevent conflict between the scroll method calls, you can check some flags and listen to scroll state change events of the scrolling content view which could be ScrollView, RecyclerView and etc. I will write some example to make it more clear for you.
If you want to use handler for example:

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLoooer()) 
val runnable = Runnable {
  scrollContent()
  handler.postDelayed(this,50)
}
var isScrolling = false
someScrollView.addOnScrollListener(object: OnScrollStateChangeListener {
  override fun onScrollStateChanged(scrollView: ScrollView,newState: Int) {
    if(newState == ScrollView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
      isScrolling = false
    } else {
      isScrolling = true
    }
  }
})
// For example I defined the amount of  scrolling 100 but you should calculate it based on the pace of singer inside the song actually
val scrollAmount = 100
private fun scrollContent(){
  if(isScorlling == true) return
  someScrollView.smoothScroll(scrollAmount,0)
}
handler.post(runnable)
```